what's the advantage of `NewType` over `TypeAlias`?
Consider the following example:

UserId = NewType('UserId', int)
ProductId = NewType('ProductId', int)

But I can also do, the following:
UserId: TypeAlias = int
ProductId: TypeAlias = int

So why should I use NewType over TypeAlias or vice versa? Are they both interchangeable?

That one doesn't explicitly hint TypeAlias, but I think it's still applicable.

Aliases don't distinguish between each other. New types do. Consider this example:
Meter = NewType('Meter', float)
Gram = NewType('Gram', float)
MeterSquared = NewType('MeterSquared', float)

def area(length: Meter, width: Meter) -> MeterSquared:
    return MeterSquared(length * width)

Now area(3, 5) won't type check, nor would area(Meter(3), Gram(5)), but area(Meter(3), Meter(5)) will. If you had defined Meter and Gram as mere type aliases, all three would type check.
Basically, a NewType is, well, a new type entirely distinct from the "base" type, just with the same underlying representation. A type alias, on the other hand, is just another name for an existing type, and the two are entirely interchangeable.

Yes, this should probably be worked into an answer on the proposed duplicate. But I think there's a subtle distinction between "what's the difference between the two" and "what's the advantage of one over the other".

The top answer on the other one does try to explain the advantage. From the first paragraph: "Having it be a subtype (your first example) instead of an alias (your second example) is useful for a situation where you want to statically verify (through something like mypy) that all InputFormats were made in a certain way."
